# Cannot access application after installing ipv6 on xp

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-xp, localhost, ipv6

I have a tomcat webapplication running on 8080 which will fetch xml from another application at 4040, both running on a xp machine. Everything was working fine until I installed IPv6. Now I cannot access the application from tomcat.

What I find strange is that the xml can be viewed using browser, but the same url does not work when used by the tomcat application. I get a ConnectionException. Changing the value to ipv4, 127.0.0.1 did not work either.

Trying to access the application from another machine did not work either.

Does anyone know whats going on here?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's the APR listener. If you don't need it, remove tcnative1.dll or change server.xml to not load it.

I'm pretty sure there must be a way to force it to listen on ipv4 as well, but by default it only listens on ipv6 if ipv6 is installed.